# row_number() in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with these situation:

[image: Table]

With my code

```
select
    ID_A,
    ID_B,
    Position,
    row_number() over (partition by ID_A, ID_B order by position) as row
from 
    TB_EXAMPLE
order by 
    ID_A, Position
```

I added a `row_number_a` column, but I want the `row_number_b` situation. Do you have any hints?

Comment: I dont get it? You already got it with your code??

Comment: How does rownumberB satisfy requirements and whats logic behind it ?

Comment: Please don't post data as an image. Post is as **text**. Other users can't interact with an image.

Comment: with my code i've done the row_number_a column, but i need row_number_b column.
I need to restart row_number_b when ID2 column change, but in ID2 column i have the first and the last value that are the same, and the count does not restart, because i think the partition is the same

Comment: Is the position actually a sequence, no gaps? It's a *gaps&islands* problem, you need to assign a group number to each row before the Row_number

Comment: yes position is a sequence without gaps

Comment: i need to delete the row wich have the same value for ID2 consecutively excluded the first value, in this case i need to delete the row with position 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19.
i tought to use row_number() to delete the row with a row_number_A != 1 but the last 2 value for ID2 are correct

Comment: You should have said that you want to delete rows from the beginning :-) I edited my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a gaps&islands problem, you need to assign a group number to each row before the Row_number. There are several ways, the following is based on the fact that the difference between two sequential number is the same as long as there's no gap in one of the sequences:

```
position rownum diff 
       1      1    0
       2      1    1
       3      1    2
       4      1    3
       5      2    3
       3      3    3
...
      22      1    21
      23      2    21
      24      2    22
```

Now all rows with the same ID_A and ID_B get the same difference if position is sequential and you can use this value in PARTITION BY:

```
with cte as 
 (

    select
         ID_A
        ,ID_B
        ,Position
        ,position -- if position is not sequential: ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by ID_A order by position)
         - ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by ID_A,ID_B order by position) as grp
    from TB_EXAMPLE
 )
select 
    ID_A
   ,ID_B
   ,Position
   ,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by ID_A, ID_B, grp order by position) as rn
from cte
order by ID_A,Position
```

Based on your comment that you actually want to delete rows, this can be simplified to a check if the previous row's values are the same as the current row's:

```
with cte as 
 (

    select
         ID_A
        ,ID_B
        ,Position
        ,case when LAG(ID_A)over(order by position) = ID_A
               and LAG(ID_B)over(order by position) = ID_B
              then 'delete'
              else 'keep'
         end as flag
    from TB_EXAMPLE
 )
select *
from cte
where flag = 'delete'
```

And as it looks like this is only based on changes in ID_B:

```
with cte as 
 (

    select
         ID_A
        ,ID_B
        ,Position
        ,case when LAG(ID_B)over(partition by ID_A order by position) = ID_B
              then 'delete'
              else 'keep'
         end as flag
    from TB_EXAMPLE
 )
select *
from cte
where flag = 'delete'
```